# Ews Java API Getting Sent emails

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I'm using EWS Java API(version 2.0) to fetch exchange emails in Java

I want to fetch all mails that are sent to this emails address ("rams@mydomain.com") from exchange box

Here is my sample code

```
 String email = "rams@mydomain.com"
 ItemView itemView = new ItemView(1000);


 SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection1 = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(
                    LogicalOperator.Or
                    );
            SearchFilter searchFilter1 = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.DisplayCc, email);
            SearchFilter searchFilter2 = new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.DisplayTo, email);
            searchFilterCollection1.add(searchFilter1);
            searchFilterCollection1.add(searchFilter2);
            FindItemsResults<Item> items = exService.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems,searchFilterCollection1,itemView);
```

I'm not getting any exception. I'm not getting any emails but actually emails are present in server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the Participants field with a query string?

```
String email = "rams@mydomain.com";
ItemView itemView = new ItemView(1000);

var queryString = String.Format("(From:=%1$s OR Participants:=%1$s)", email);

FindItemsResults<Item> items = exService.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, 
                                                  queryString, itemView);
```

Comment: I tried the way you suggested , it worked for first time , I'm able to fetch all sent items as per my search criteria.  But the problem is it's not fetching latest sent items if I run the same query next time. It's returning items till the timestamp when I ran my query first time.